# Why do i receive an 'x' undefined error with ode23s but not with ode23 or ode15s in OCTAVE?

Tags: matlab, undefined, octave, ode

I'm trying to solve some ODEs in OCTAVE with solver ode23s (the exact same algorithm is running perfectly in Matlab) but i'm receiving an 'x' undefined error, while that doesn't happen when i'm using the solvers ode23 or ode15s even though that's the only change i'm making.

Below you can see the mentioned code and the error:

```
    model = [Fg1 Fg2 ui mi ... gi]; %model is a vector of (1,77) 
    options = odeset('RelTol',1e-4,'AbsTol',5e-6*ones(16,1));
    [T,Y] = ode23s(@odesys_test,0:dt:10,init,options,model);
```

The function code:

```
function [dx] = odesys_test(t,x,model)

global tt

Fg1 = model(1);
```

The error:

error: 'model' undefined near line 5, column 5

error: called from
odesys_test at line 5 column 5
runge_kutta_23s at line 121 column 5
integrate_adaptive at line 135 column 39
ode23s at line 217 column 12
DOF2_test at line 189 column 15

Comment: Please add the code. Without a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) no one will be able to help you with your question.

Answer (score 0):

According to octave's documentation, the syntax is

```
[T, Y] = ode23s (FUN, TRANGE, INIT, ODE_OPT)
```

You are passing an extra `model` parameter which is not part of the function's signature.

Also the `odesys_test` function you created does not fulfill the specification expected by `ode23s`. Read the documentation carefully.

Perhaps what you mean to do is simply create an anonymous function which *does* fulfill the specification, and use that to 'wrap' around your odesys_test function, e.g.

```
[T,Y] = ode23s( @(t, x) odesys_test(t, x, model), 0:dt:10, init, options,model );
```